# Message Element cause parent to expand

Tags: html, css

I've been banging my head on this one for a while.

Here's my problem: I'm building a library to simplify AJAX calls and to display error messages neatly inline on a form.

---

#### The problem:

When the message is displayed, the form shifts width.

- The form needs to be dynamically sized
- The message can be multiple lines

**The desired result:**

The message should fill based on the width of the form, and not cause the form to change.

---

#### The code:

HTML:

```
<div class="absolute-wrapper">
<form class="wrapper">
    <label>
        Foobar:
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
    </label>
    <div class="message" id="Message">
        Error: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.absolute-wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;left:0;
        }
.wrapper { 
        background:#f0f0f0; 
        padding:10px;
        }

div.message { color:red; background:#fee; 
              width:100%;/* should be 100% of the form, but it is not */
            }
```

---

I made a **JSFiddle** for this: http://jsfiddle.net/redolent1/2WvVL/

Can this be done in pure CSS?

Comment: you obviously need some script to show the message, show why not just use script to set its width? a pure CSS solution is not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

my version

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBCrn)

**HTML**

```
<div class="absolute-wrapper">
<form class="wrapper">
    <label>
        Foo Bar:
        <input class="text" type="text" name="name"/>
    </label>
    <div class="message" id="Message">
    </div>
    <p> 
        Click submit to test: 
        <input type="submit"/>
    </p>
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.absolute-wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;left:0;
    display: block;
        }
.wrapper { 
        background:#f0f0f0; 
        padding:10px;
        }

div.message { color:red; background:#fee; }
div.message {
        display:none;
        }
.text {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This this code on *.absolute-wrapper*
.

```
absolute-wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without specifying a width?

Comment: I' am afraid theirs no other way.

Comment: If you want, then you can remove "position: absolute;" then you won't need width anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the initial width of your absolute-wrapper class,
Add this inside your .absolute-wrapper class

```
width: 256px;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without specifying a width?

Comment: It's like being strict telling your browser to limit the width of your absolute-wrapper class. Without specifying the width, it will auto adjust based on the length of your text.

Comment: You could also try playing with the min-width and max-width property.